# Compare strings in Forth

Tags: forth

I enter strings from the keyboard and compare them. But it never returns 0 even if the strings are equal.

```
CREATE word1 14 ALLOT
: .getword1 word1 14 BLANK word1 14 EXPECT ;

CREATE word2 14 ALLOT
: .getword2 word2 14 BLANK word2 14 EXPECT ;

: input_words
  ." " CR
  ." First word:" CR
  .getword1
  ." " CR
  ." Second word:" CR
  .getword2
  word2
  word1
  word1 word2 compare
  ." " CR
  .s
  ;
```

It never returns 0 for my strings:

```
First word:
e
Second word:
e
<1> 1
```

Is there something wrong with the definitions?

Answer (score 3):

`compare` has the following stack signature ( cstr1 count1 cstr2 count2 -- n ). It requires the addresses of the string and their counts (lengths)

```
create word1 ," Test" \ Store counted string in word1
create word2 ," Test" \ Store counted string in word2
word1 count type Test ok
word2 count type Test ok
word1 . word2 .  4992752 4992848  ok  \ addresses of word1 and word2
word1 count word2 count .s compare
DATA STACK
 top
          4 0000:0004    \ count2
    4992849 004C:2F51    \ address word2 + 1
          4 0000:0004    \ count1
    4992753 004C:2EF1    \ address word1 + 1
ok-1
. 0  ok
```

Further comparisons

```
char S word1 1+ c!  ok  \ Change the T in word1 to an S
word1 count type Sest ok
word1 count word2 count compare . -1  ok

char R word2 1+ c!  ok  \ Change the T in word1 to an R
word2 count type Rest ok
word1 count word2 count compare . 1  ok
```

I don't have an EXPECT word on my system to test your code but I suspect various items are left on the stack by your `getwordx` words that means the comparison doesn't cause an exception but doesn't do the comparisons you expect.

Edit: An answer with EXPECT implemented.

```
\ Creating ANS forth EXPECT. I have ACCEPT not EXPECT in my Forth
CELL USER SPAN
: EXPECT  \ addr ct -- 
  ACCEPT SPAN ! ;

\ Answer to question
: getword  \ addr ct -- 
  2DUP BL FILL    \ Fill addr for count with blanks
  EXPECT ;        \ Refill addr with characters typed at the prompt.

CREATE word1 14 ALLOT
CREATE word2 14 ALLOT

: wtype  \  addr -- ;
  14 -TRAILING TYPE ;

: input_words  \ ;
  CR ." First  Word : " word1 14 getword
  CR ." Second Word : " word2 14 getword
  CR word1 wtype 5 SPACES word2 wtype
  CR word1 14 word2 14 compare .
;
```

As both buffers are filled with blanks for any unused characters the comparison is still valid.

```
input_words 
First  Word : Test 
Second Word : Test 
Test     Test
0  ok
input_words 
First  Word : Rest 
Second Word : Test 
Rest     Test
-1  ok
```

Comment: @Kmssr.  Note `FILL` here is the ANS forth `FILL \ addr ct char -- ;` which fills addr to addr+ct-1 with char.  Not the `fill` from your next question.